# Include RawRecord in dynamic objects returned from CsvHelper GetRecords

Tags: csvhelper

I have this working when converting to Class objects, by using a `Configuration.RegisterClassMap` (in essence I'm mapping `row.Context.RawRecord` to a property on my Class called `RawRecord`):

```cs
public sealed class RecordMap : ClassMap<CsvRecord>
{
    public RecordMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        Map(m => m.RawRecord).ConvertUsing(row => row.Context.RawRecord.Replace("\r\n", ""));
    }
}
```

...but I'm wanting to move away from needing the Class Object (in this example `CsvRecord`), and rather use a dynamic object with `csv.GetRecords<dynamic>()`. This is working for me except for the fact that I haven't been able to work out how to get the `RawRecord`. Ideally if I could add some configuration to simply add it as a new column on the dynamic object, but I can't find anything like that.

I'm using linq to build a list of Domain Objects (`Individuals`), which includes grouping CSV rows, so I don't want to be iterating through each record manually:

```cs
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
{
    csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) => Regex.Replace(header, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");

    var dateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var individuals = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList().Where(r => r.GroupType == "Individual").
        GroupBy(r => r.GroupID).
        Select(g => new Individual(
            // Include constructor arguments here
            g.Key,
            g.First().Name1
            // ...
            // Include an array of all raw CSV records that have been used to generate this object
            // This currently fails
            g.Select(r => r.RawRecord).Cast<string>().ToArray()
        )).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do it with configuration.

```cs
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
{
    csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) => Regex.Replace(header, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");

    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();

    var records = new List<dynamic>();

    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var record = csv.GetRecord<dynamic>();
        record.RawRecord = csv.Context.RawRecord.Replace("\r\n", "");
        records.Add(record);
    }

    var dateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var individuals = records.Where(r => r.GroupType == "Individual").
        GroupBy(r => r.GroupID).
        Select(g => new Individual(
            // Include constructor arguments here
            g.Key,
            g.First().Name1
            // ...
            // Include an array of all raw CSV records that have been used to generate this object
            // This currently fails
            g.Select(r => r.RawRecord).Cast<string>().ToArray()
        )).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, I thought I could probably just loop over the CSV with `csv.Read()` (I saw some examples of that), but was really hoping for something a little more elegant. I'm assuming this won't make much difference to the performance (`csv.GetRecords` would need to do a loop internally anyway), but it just makes for slightly less succinct code.

That said, your example does solve the problem, thanks so much for the response and the code example.

Comment: Yes `csv.GetRecords` does loop internally using `csv.GetRecord`.